# How to create same route with json file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I have an `Api` Route in `Nodejs`, this `Api` route is fetching the conversation a list from `mongodb`. I want to create same `route` if  the `data` is stored in a `json` file

```
router.get("/conversations", (req, res) => {
  let from = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jwtUser.id);
  Conversation.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "recipients",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "recipientObj",
      },
    },
  ])
    .match({ recipients: { $all: [{ $elemMatch: { $eq: from } }] } })
    .project({
      "recipientObj.password": 0,
      "recipientObj.__v": 0,
      "recipientObj.date": 0,
    })
    .exec((err, conversations) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failure" }));
        res.sendStatus(500);
      } else {
        res.send(conversations);
      }
    });
});
```

[image: The data is stored in the mongodb in this format]

Comment: Do you want to use the same endpoint for two different cases?

Comment: yes  GalAbra: I want to create same `API`  if the data is stored in `JSON` file